# Generate Flame Graph from JFR dump with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, jfr, flamegraph

IDEA generates those neat flame graphs when using "Run with Java Flight Recorder".

[image]

While I know of [external tools](https://github.com/chrishantha/jfr-flame-graph) capable of this, is it possible to generate those flame graphs from existing jfr dumps with IDEA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can open any exisiting jfr report (Main menu/Run/Open Profiler Snapshot), and if it contains sampling, flame graph will also be available.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I can see JNI Global references only, while jmc shows flame graph.

Comment: Please file a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue

Comment: I will leave that to jetbrains, for now I am good with async-profiler provided converter.jar